# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered

Tags: windows, oracle, oledb

This error has been documented thousands of times, and I have been googling it for hours - so, yes, possible duplicate. Unfortunately, I still have this issue. I have tried what others have said: registering dll by hand, re-run install, unblocking the downloaded odac files, using elevated command prompts, all debug/release and x86/x64/Any combinations, etc... nothing worked for me, so maybe one of you has a brilliant (new) idea ?

- Windows Server 2012 Standard, .Net 4.5 installed
- 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
- application is a VS2015 windows service compiled in x64 Release .Net 4.5
- installed (X-Copy version) Oracle OleDB files from the ODAC112040XCopy_64bit.zip official from Oracle OTN

There is no Oracle database on this server. The OleDB driver will be used to communicate with another machine where Oracle 11.2 is installed and running.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you install Oracle client 11.2 64-bit?

Comment: Open your Registry and check value `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3F63C36E-51A3-11D2-BB7D-00C04FA30080}\InprocServer32`. Does it point to correct location of file `OraOLEDB11.dll`?

Comment: Thank you Wernfried for taking some time to look at this.

Comment: Yes Oracle instant Client is also installed. I also have this reg key and correct pointer to dll file.

Comment: Is the folder in PATH variable?

Comment: Yes, the PATH env. variable contains the full path to OraOLEDB11.dll

Comment: Do you have more than one Oracle client installed?

Comment: Only one Oracle client.

Comment: Try Process Explorer, it should show what the application tries to load and where it fails.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Procexp doesn't show any application which my code tries to start. Note that the application is a windows service. COuld it be a rights issue ? It's installed/running as Local System. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

X-COPY version of ODP .NET needs to be self-managed. So, you need to add in you .NET application a dllpath pointing to location of your oracledataaccess.dll OR you manually register the driver using "configure.bat" located in your oracle X-copy directory.